# BroadcastReceiver для системных ошибок

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

Есть проблема с UI тестами, заключающаяся в том, что после некорректной работы камеры, происходит всплывание системного `alertDialog`-a, в котором содержится сообщение, что "Unfortunately, Camera has been stopped", что соотвественно ведет к дальнейшему `INJECT_PERMISSION`. Есть ли возможность зарегистрировать свой собственный broadCastReceiver системных ошибок? Буду признателен любому совету.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Broadcast` не запускается при ошибке, по крайней мере я не знаю таковых. Полный список бродкастов [можно увидеть здесь](https://github.com/ViliusKraujutis/AndroidBroadcastsMonitor/wiki/List-of-all-Broadcast-Intent-actions.-API-17) - для API 17, но для новых API не так много и прибавилось.

Советую присмотреться к `Camera.ErrorCallback` или к семейству колбэков из `android.hardware.camera2`